# Emberjs model rendering

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I just started learning emberjs and wanted to display a list of data from the models. My app.js:

```
var h= [{
name: "Hi",
},
{
name: "Hello",
}
];
App.ListsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function(){
    return h;
}
});
```

my corresponding lists handlebar:

```
<div id="list">
    <ul>
        {{#each}}
        <li>
        {{ name }}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</div>
```

I get the error as:

```
Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed (generated lists controller)
```

What is that I can do to display those?

Comment: It would be easier if you create a http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ with your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#each` wants to iterate over a list. Since you didn't give it an argument, it defaults to trying to iterate over your `ListsController`. Unfortunately, since you didn't define it, the controller was auto-generated based on the plain `Ember.Controller`. Thus, the error.

Two ways to fix this:

1) Make `ListsController` into an `ArrayController`

```js
App.ListsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({});
```

2) Tell `#each` to target your model instead of controller.

```html
<div id="list">
    <ul>
        {{#each model}}
            <li>{{ name }}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</div>
```